# How do I exclude a file from an Angular deployment

Tags: angular, ng-build

I am loading some data from a JSON file in my Angular (19.1) app using `HTTP` `GET`.

```
  urlDataFile = './assets/data.json';
  data: any = null;

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.loadData().subscribe((res) => {
        this.data = res;
    });
  }

  private loadData() {
    return this._http.get(this.urlDataFile);
  }
```

The data file that I develop with, and is held in source control, is a dummy/test file.

Once the application is built for distribution and deployed, the data file will be replaced with an actual data file.

Normally (using as basic default configuration as possible), the file from `./src/assets/data.json` gets copied to `./dist/assets/data.json` when I do `ng build`.

How can I exclude just this one file `./src/assets/data.json` from being included in my distribution?

Comment: Use an asset specification object in your `angular.json`. In particular there's an option for ignore. See [docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration)

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewAllen, putting ```{
"glob": "**/*",
"input": "src/assets/",
"ignore": ["**/data.json"],
"output": "/assets/"
}``` in place of `"src/assets/"` in angular.json did exclude the file from the distribution. But it also excluded it in dev using `ng serve`. How can I continue to make use of the file for development (`ng serve`) and exclude it from the build for distribution (`ng build`)?

Comment: I would expect you can specify per configuration i.e. path targets > build > configuration > production/development > assets, as above. Docs mention *Each build target configuration can...*